# How to validate IPv6 which has scope ID?

Tags: java, guava, ipv6, apache-commons

I tried apache commons validator and Guava. Both libraries return invalid for an IPv6 address which has scope ID(%15 in given example) in it. eg. fe80::8b2:d61e:e5c:b333%15

Is there any java library which considers it a valid IPv6 address?

Comment: I have yet to find any web application which understands the scope of a Link-Local address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard java.net classes InetAddress/Inet6Address seem to parse it correctly, e.g.

```
InetAddress inet6Address = Inet6Address.getByName("fe80::8b2:d61e:e5c:b333%15");
```

btw. indeed AC (1.5.1) InetAddressValidator and Guava (19.0) InetAddresses seem to fail on this

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like it should be filed as a bug against each project.

Comment: Note that Inet6Address.getByName will throw  UnkownHostException if the interface in the scope does not exist on the machine running the jvm. This makes it unsuitable for validating _any_ IPv6

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, the standard Java libraries parse the scope and store it as well.

Also, the [open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) also supports scope ids.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.  Here is example source:

```
IPAddressString ipAddrString = new IPAddressString("fe80::8b2:d61e:e5c:b333%15");
IPAddress addr = ipAddrString.getAddress();
if(addr.isIPv6()) {
    IPv6Address ipv6Addr = addr.toIPv6();
    String zone = ipv6Addr.getZone();
    IPv6Address noZoneAddr = new IPv6Address(ipv6Addr.getBytes());
    System.out.println(zone);
    System.out.println(noZoneAddr);
}
```

output:

```
15
fe80::8b2:d61e:e5c:b333
```